# Good introduction to OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I'm interested in learning about rendering and "the whole 2D/3D stuff", especially in OpenGL/C#. There are thousands of search results on Google, so I was wondering if you have any recommendations which to pick, and how to approach the issue - is it possible to become proficient without a teacher? - Are there great books on the topic?

My background: I have been programming in C++/Java/C# for years. I got basic math skills but lack knowledge once it comes to basic university level. The reason for digging into this topic is a company project as well as personal interest.

Comment: Ooops, looks like a dupe! Didn't show up when I wrote the question :\

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a good book for learning OpenGL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62540/whats-a-good-book-for-learning-opengl)

Comment: Should I delete this question? Or keep it for future searches?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: That's a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use OpenGL in C#, go for [OpenTK](http://opentk.com) which is an amazing C# library that let's you use everything OpenGL, OpenAL and OpenCL have to offer from a typesafe .NET environment.  Their website has very good tutorials as well.  Once that is done, you can usually choose OpenGL tutorials and translate them to OpenTK syntax without much trouble.  [NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net) has very good OpenGL tutorials.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes, I'm already using OpenTK - it looks very nice!

Comment: Then definitely [Nehe](http://nehe.gamedev.net) and [Beginning OpenGL](http://www.amazon.ca/Beginning-OpenGL-Game-Programming-Second/dp/159863528X) if you want a book.  OpenTK specific books and websites are a lot rarer.  Actually I never saw a book.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the OpenGL Super Bible 5th Edition too. It's got all the new shader stuff (though the code examples are all in C++).

Answer (score 1):

the red book is very good.

http://www.opengl.org/documentation/red_book/

i'd say it is the only book you need to get started